# How to make an action bar like the Zomato app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

[image]

> Like this in the Zomato app

[image]

> This is the screen which opens when I click on the action bar location

I am using Android Studio 2.2 with `targetSdkVersion` 23

Comment: What do you mean by scroll down menu ?Can you share an image of the app in scrolled down state?

Comment: It is not exactly a scroll sown menu but a new activity. My bad

Comment: Exactly! There is on a click listener for the location text in the actiobar/toolbar and then onclick they are starting a new acitivty to choose the location. And please upvote the comment if you find it useful.

Comment: no.. but how do i add the search bar to the action bar on the other screen

Comment: There is a class called SearchView. Please refer this [link](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/) for more info.

Comment: in that you have to click on the search button for the search bar to open.
what i need is something which remains open